# React application boiler plate runs blank

Tags: reactjs, redux

https://github.com/btomashvili/react-redux-firebase-boilerplate

Can anyone give me directions on how to get this application running every time i follow the install instructions it runs on localhost:3000 as a blank screen? Thanks !

found these errors in the console also any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
Error: Given action "FETCH_FIREBASE_USER", reducer "currentUser" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.
    at combination (combineReducers.js:136)
    at dispatch (createStore.js:178)
    at redux-logger.js:1
    at index.js:28
    at Object.fetchUser (bindActionCreators.js:7)
    at new App (app.jsx:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:148)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:37)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:225)


Uncaught Error: Given action "FETCH_FIREBASE_USER", reducer "currentUser" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.
    at combination (combineReducers.js:136)
    at dispatch (createStore.js:178)
    at redux-logger.js:1
    at index.js:28
    at Object.fetchUser (bindActionCreators.js:7)
    at new App (app.jsx:15)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:148)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.wrapper [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:37)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:225)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very obvious. Because it can not be able to return state according to action `FETCH_FIREBASE_USER`. In the quick solution just return `state`

```
case FETCH_FIREBASE_USER:
    return state;
    // return fetchUser(); Comment this out
```

And when you have proper setup from `FIREBASE` service. Get back that line again.